# Boto3: When using get_paginator(), do I still need to check for "NextToken"?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, paginator, aws-organizations

I am defining a method which fetches all accountIDs from an organization.

If I am using `get_paginator('list_accounts')`, then am I okay if I do not check the `NextToken`?

Code to get the list of all AWS account IDs in the organization:

```
def get_all_account_ids():
    org_client = boto3.client('organizations')
    paginator = org_client.get_paginator('list_accounts')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate()

    account_ids = []
    for page in page_iterator:        
        for acct in page['Accounts']:
            print(acct['Id']) # print the account id

            # add to account_ids list
            account_ids.append(acct['Id'])

    return account_ids
```

I have seen examples of using either `get_paginator()` call or `while` loop checking for `NextToken`. But I have not seen example using both `paginator` and `NextToken`?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to check `NextToken`. That's the point of [paginators](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html):

> Paginators are a feature of boto3 that act as an abstraction over the process of iterating over an **entire result set** of a truncated API operation.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin. Greatly appreciate this clarification & explanation.